# Missing Advertising ID consequence

Tags: android, ads, google-advertising-id

Android 13 (API 33) introduces changes to advertising ID.
It says:

```
Apps that use advertising ID and target Android 13 or later must declare the
com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in their app manifest. 
If you don't include this permission, your advertising identifier will be zeroed out, 
any attempts to access the identifier will receive a string of zeros instead of the identifier
```

I don't declare `om.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID`.
So, `advertising identifier will be zeroed out`. What happens now ?
No ads will be displayed? Or just less relevant ads? (My app displays full-screen InterstitialAds)

Thanks